# LayoutManager for RecyclerView with different items width

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView and I used StaggeredGridLayoutManager for its layout manager. Every item has different width and I don't know how wide is every item.
 My code:

```
StaggeredGridLayoutManager stagedLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(4, VERTICAL);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(stagedLayoutManager);
```

The result is some thing looks like this:
[image]

But I want to have some thing looks like this one:[image]

Please guid me how can I achieve this purpose? Thanks

Comment: You want to fill the first row, when its full continue on the second row and so on. All items in one row should stretch to fill the whole row. And the list should scroll vertically. Is this correct?

Comment: @EugenPechanec Yes I want to fill first row and when its full continue on the second row and so on but I don't want to stretch all items in one row to fill the whole row. Actually all items in one row should retain their width and I don't want the spaces between them.

Comment: Do you have a solution?

Comment: @DuosDuo use this library https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

Answer (score 1):

`StaggeredGridLayoutManager` works on a grid. You set it to vertical with 4 columns, so it will have 4 columns.

Every item in each column now can have a varying height and it will "stagger". But every item still occupies the whole column.

---

This will *not* work for width and height. It is still a grid and every item will either get the whole width of the column (or height of the row, if you make it horizontal).

---

You will have to write your own LayoutManager or try to use [FlexBoxLayout (still alpha)](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) which might be able to do what you want.

Comment: I second the FlexBoxLayoutManager choice. David, please provide more details directly in your answer.